# Python : Removing a List from List of List?

Tags: python, performance, list, python-3.x

I have a set say

```
char={'J','A'}
```

and a list of list

```
content = [[1,'J', 2], [2, 'K', 3], [2, 'A', 3], [3,'A', 9], [5, 'J', 9]]
```

I am trying to remove the list items in list `content`, which don't have `'J' & 'A'`
What I did is

```
li = list(char)
char1= np.array(li)
content=np.array(content)
new_content=[]
for alphabet in content:
    if alphabet[1] in char1:
        new_content.append(alphabet)
print(new_content)
```

Is there any efficient way of writing? If `char` and `content` has more no of elements, then the computation takes long time.

Comment: ... why are you using `np.array` there? `numpy` is efficient when performing *vector* operations, but you are simply looping.

Comment: The question is a bit unclear. Do you want to remove all the lists in `content` which contain 'J' OR 'A'? Do you want to remove all the lists in `content` which contain 'J' AND 'A'? Do you want to remove 'J' and 'A' from every list in `content`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> content = [[1,'J', 2], [2, 'K', 3], [2, 'A', 3], [3,'A', 9], [5, 'J', 9]]
>>> char={'J','A'}
```

All lists in `content` which have 'J' AND 'A':

```
>>> [x for x in content if all(c in x for c in char)]
[]
```

All lists in `content` which have 'J' OR 'A':

```
>>> [x for x in content if any(c in x for c in char)]
[[1, 'J', 2], [2, 'A', 3], [3, 'A', 9], [5, 'J', 9]]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
content = [[1,'J', 2], [2, 'K', 3], [2, 'A', 3], [3,'A', 9], [5, 'J', 9]]
whitelist = {'J','A'}

remove = set()
for i,sub in enumerate(content):
    if sub[1] not in whitelist: remove.add(i)

content = [sub for i,sub in enumerate(content) if i not in whitelist]
```

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: true. You should post that as an answer

Answer (score 2):

```
content = [[1,'J', 2], [2, 'K', 3], [2, 'A', 3], [3,'A', 9], [5, 'J', 9]]
whitelist = {'J','A'}

i = 0
while i<len(content):
    if content[i][1] not in whitelist:
        blacklist.pop(i)
        continue
    i += 1
```

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: No. If you pop an item from the list, then you do not want to increment the index, as what used to be at index `n+1` will be at index `n` after the `pop`

Answer (score 1):

I would write it like this

```
char={'J','A'}
content = [[1,'J', 2], [2, 'K', 3], [2, 'A', 3], [3,'A', 9], [5, 'J', 9]]

filter(lambda x: all([i in char for i in x]), content)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
content = [[1,'J', 2], [2, 'K', 3], [2, 'A', 3], [3,'A', 9], [5, 'J', 9]]
whitelist = {'J','A'}

content = [sub for sub in content if sub[1] not in whitelist]
```